# Setting Ubuntu gdb to print details every step (like in Kali Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, gdb

In the pre-installed gdb in Kali Linux, details such as the values of registers and the stack as well as the following instructions are printed each step, as shown here: [image]

However, in Ubuntu, the gdb looks like this: [image]

I want gdb to print those details every step in Ubuntu, just like in Kali.

Is there a setting for that? Thanks!

Comment: As you can see from the `gef>` prompt, it's using [gef](https://github.com/hugsy/gef/).